# What's the difference between an exciton and a geminate pair?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, solar-cells

In the context of organic solar cells, electron-hole dissociation is sometimes mentioned with regard to excitons (refs [1](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00339-003-2182-9), [2](http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.81.205307)) and sometime with regard to geminate pairs (refs [3](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0009261499010143), [4](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticleLanding/2012/EE/C2EE21376A)).

Also, exciton binding energy is 10meV (Wannier) - 1eV (Frenkel), while geminate pair binding energy is generally up to 0.5eV.

So what's the difference between an exciton and a geminate pair?

Answer (score 1):

A geminate pair can be considered as a charge-transfer exciton, i.e., when an electron from the electron-hole (exciton) pair in some homogeneous material experiences a transfer through the interface between electron donor and electron acceptor materials. The electron in the electron-accepting material and the hole in the electron-donor material remain bound by electrostatic interaction, so they exist as a geminate pair. The binding energy of this pair is less as compared to the exciton in the homogeneous medium by the difference in electron affinities of the contacting materials.